# How can I bounce a ball with gravity?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to bounce a ball around a canvas with gravity. Every time the ball hits the side or bottom walls, the speed of x and y should decrease. The following code has not been working because the ball just falls through the walls.

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height ="200"></canvas>

    var Ball=function(color) {
        this.color=color;
        this.x =100;
        this.y =100;
        this.xSpeed =5;
        this.ySpeed =3;

    };
```

}

```
    Ball.prototype.move =function () {
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
    };

    Ball.prototype.checkCollison =function () {
        if(this.x < 0 ) {
            if(this.xSpeed >0){
                this.xSpeed--;
            }else if(this.xSpeed<0) {
                this.xSpeed++;
            }

            this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        }else if(this.x >200) {
            if(this.xSpeed >0){
                this.xSpeed--;
            }else if(this.xSpeed<0) {
                this.xSpeed++;

            this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;

        }else if(this.y < 0 ) {
            if(this.ySpeed>0) {
                this.ySpeed--;
            }else if(this.ySpeed<0) {
                this.ySpeed++;
            }
            this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
        }
    }
    };
```

Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: `The following code has not been working` could you be a little more specific with the exact problem you're having? That could be anything between "the ball gets stuck in the wall" and "my computer is overheating".

Comment: the code looks like it should be doing what you say (though, there is no hint of any *gravity* in your code) the ball should slow down with every hit as you say, but if there's code that simulates gravity, then of course the ball's vertical velocity will change accordingly

Comment: When I run this code the ball goes straight through the walls. It just falls through, is there anything else you would like to know?

Comment: Where did the 300 come from?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code then?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a [mcve]. As Jaromanda X said, other than not resetting the values to the boundaries, everything else looks like it should work as expected, but without an actual example to verify this, all possible suggestions are nothing more than speculation.

Comment: Ill give the full code then

Comment: I would like to give you the full code so that you can get an idea of the problem.

Comment: It's hard to summarize the code without leaving out important parts

Comment: @RebeccaPhillips Does the ball have a radius?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I finally figured out the answer to this part of code:

```
Ball.prototype.checkCollison =function () {
    if(this.x <= 0 ) {

        if(this.xSpeed <0)
            this.xSpeed++;
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        this.x=1;

    }
    else if( this.x >= 200) {
        if(this.xSpeed > 0)
            this.xSpeed--;
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        this.x--;

    }

    else if(  this.y >= 200) {
        if(this.ySpeed >0)
            this.ySpeed--;
        this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
        this.y--;
    }
    else if(this.y<=0) {
        this.ySpeed=-this.ySpeed;



    }
};
```

Thank all of you though for trying to help, I appreciate the effort.